# SVG Sprite with style attributes on different grouping tags

Tags: css, svg

I have a sprite map SVG, and example usage is like this:

```
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="block w-full h-full block"><use xlink:href="/src/assets/sprite.svg?t=123#triangle"></use></svg>
```

This loads the triangle SVG in Shadow DOM like so:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" fill="currentColor" id="battery_distributor"><path d="M150 5 75 200h150Z"></path></svg>
```

However, the triangle SVG is set like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
    <path d="M150 5 L75 200 L225 200 Z" style="fill: none; stroke: green; stroke-width: 3" />
</svg>
```

But it appears filled in as black on the output DOM via the sprite.

My guess is because the `vite-svg-sprite-wrapper` plugin I use for building the sprite map
https://github.com/vshepel/vite-svg-sprite-wrapper is stripping the style attribute away.

Is there another method to be able to add SVG files via one single React Typescript component in Vite which still support custom style attributes on different grouping `g` tags?

The docs for that plugin link to this SVG Sprite tool
https://github.com/svg-sprite/svg-sprite/

Which in turn mentions it uses svgo - https://github.com/svg/svgo

---

EDIT:
The actual SVG has something like this, just fake path numbers. The issue is that the first grouping child using stroke displays correctly but the 2nd grouping child using fill does not display, as I have `color: transparent` to try to avoid the weird background clipping grey colour:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
    <g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,200,500)" opacity="1" style="display: block;">
            <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-opacity="0" stroke-dasharray="10"
                    stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0.35" stroke-width="3"
                    d="M-20, 100">
                </path>
            </g>
            <g opacity="1" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill-opacity="0" stroke-dasharray="10"
                    stroke="rgb(180,211,46)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="3"
                    d="M-20, 100">
                </path>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,0)" opacity="1" style="display: block;">
            <g opacity="1"
                transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1,0)">
                <path fill="rgb(0,0,0)" fill-opacity="0.35"
                    d="M1, -28z">
                </path>
            </g>
            <g opacity="1"
                transform="matrix(0, 0, 1, 1)">
                <path fill="rgb(180,211,46)" fill-opacity="1"
                    d="M1, -28z">
                </path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Actually a good idea to remove styles from a symbol/def element to enable style overrides for the `<use>`  instance. You may ask the author in the github issues section if  the tool provides a config parameter to retain styles

Comment: Hmm, but the actual SVG is two grouping tags, first grouping is using stroke, and 2nd grouping is using fill. The fill grouping (using style attribute on the `g` tag) is just not working since I set `color: transparent` on the `svg` via CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix, so basically the `vite-svg-sprite-wrapper` Vite plugin is a wrapper for `svg-sprite` but this uses `svgo`

After reading through all the docs, there is a `sprite` config option which configures how `svg-sprite` works. In that it has an option for configuring the tranformation of `svgo` using `shape.transform`

I want to keep the same default preset, and only ovveride the `removeStyleElemets` plugin for `svgo`, thus my final code is now:

```
ViteSvgSpriteWrapper({
        icons: 'public/animations/*.svg',
        outputDir: 'src/assets',
        sprite: {
          shape: {
            transform: [{
              svgo: {
                plugins: [{
                  name: 'preset-default',
                  params: {
                    overrides: {
                      removeStyleElement: false,
                    }
                  }
                }]
              }
            }]
          }
        }
      }),
```

...and this works, the style attributes are kept on the `g` tags.